# Is there a pattern to conversion between classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class, from a native library, I want to convert to my own type, and I need to do that in several places. I created, then, a static method, so I don't need to repeat the instantiation of the class in so many places, but somehow it doesn't seem right.

If there is a need to create a conversion from 8 different types, I would have 8 different methods of conversion all inside the Record.

Is this the best way to do it, or is there any known pattern that covers this subject?

```
class Record
{
  public String Id { get; set; }
  public String FirstName { get; set; }
  public String LastName { get; set; }
  public String FingerPrints { get; set; }

  //
  // This is a simplification of the method and in fact, I created several of
  // them, and the class doesn't look clean anymore.
  //
  public static Record CreateFromMaciRecord(MaciRecord maci)
  {
    return new Record
      {
        Id = maci.GetRecordId(),
        FirstName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(maci.GetUserDataField("first_name")),
        LastName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(maci.GetUserDataField("name"))
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: automapper is an opensource library which can help.

Comment: The problem is that if I have several types to convert, there will be a need for several methods as well, so the class doesn't look clean and small anymore. It appears that the conversion is misplaced.

Comment: Not 100% sure with the limited context, but there does exist an [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a constructor or a static factory method, you could introduce extension methods.  EG

```
static class Conversions
{
    public static Record ToRecord(this MaciRecord maci) => new Record
    {
        Id = maci.GetRecordId(),
        FirstName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(maci.GetUserDataField("first_name")),
        LastName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(maci.GetUserDataField("name"))
    };
}
```

Which you would call like

```
  var maciRecord = ...;
  var record = maciRecord.ToRecord();
```

Comment: That's nice, looks cleaner when I do have to have several conversions.

Comment: And the nifty thing about Extension Methods is that if you don't import their Namespace they disappear.

Comment: Still, prefer the factory pattern, mainly because it's easy to stub.

Answer (score 1):

You can always provide an implicit conversion in the `Record` and simply do:

```
Record record = someMaciRecord;
```

Add this to the `Record`.

```
public static implicit operator Record(MaciRecord maci) 
{
     return new Record
     {
         Id = maci.GetRecordId(),
         FirstName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(maci.GetUserDataField("first_name")),
         LastName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(maci.GetUserDataField("name"))
     };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your *Record* is converting an interface of *MaciRecord* so as to work with rest of the application then I would recommend *Class or Object Adapter GOF design pattern*. If *Record* is adding new functionality to *MaciRecord*, then its an opportunity for *Decorator GOF design pattern*. Necessarily we are asking for Wrapper over *MaciRecord*. Point to be noted here is that both these design patterns are also known as *Wrapper*.